# MVC3 routes interfering with JS paths

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, routes

I have the following route defined:

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "StateResults", url: "{state}/{searchTerm}", defaults: new { controller = "Results", action = "SearchState" });
```

In one of my shared chtml files I have the following defined:

```
 <script src="@Url.Content("Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I understand why the JS is not getting loaded, but how do I get around this?  I get around this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [ignore routes for JS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd505203.aspx)

```
IgnoreRoute("{file}.js");
```

---

As an alternative method you can use the constraint parameter to avoid files ending with `js`

```
routes.MapRoute("StateResults", "{state}/{searchTerm}",
    new { controller = "Results", action = "SearchState" },
    new { searchTerm = @".*?([^js])$" }); // regex not tested
```

[RouteCollectionExtensions.MapRoute Method (RouteCollection, String, String, Object, Object) from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460520.aspx)

```
constraints
    Type: System.Object
    A set of expressions that specify values for the url parameter.
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set up the routes that it ignores .js files.

a good description is found here:
http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2009/04/03/asp-net-mvc-best-practices-part-2.aspx

something like this will do the trick:

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{file}.js");
```

Comment: I wasn't able to get this working with the IgnoreRoute option, but setting a constraint did work.